# Javascript Run for loop every x seconds

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have a for loop like so:

```
for(int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
    MyFunc(i);
}
```

How would I have the program run every 3 seconds so the program would run MyFunc(0) ..wait 3 sec.. MyFunc(1) ..wait 3 sec.. etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a different delay for each iteration:

```
for(var i=0; i < 10; i++) {
    runIt(i);
}

function runIt(i) {
    setTimeout(function(){ 
       MyFunc(i);
    }, i * 3000);
}
```

See it in action here:

```js
for(var i=0; i < 10; i++) {
    runIt(i);
}

function runIt(i) {
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      //MyFunc(i);
      document.body.innerHTML = i;
    }, i * 3000);
}
```

Comment: While this works, it's worth to point out that this is probably not scalable. There are only so many timeouts you should have...